# Change background image in mobile when device motion is changed

Tags: jquery, devicemotion

I am trying to change the background image when mobile device motion is changed (Like you make the device top, left or right, or up-down motion). i am using this code, issue is its start working immediately, even I don't change the motion of device by hand. its keep on updating always in a loop.

what I want when I change the mobile device a bit right or left or up down, it should change image than, any idea how I can make it working:

```
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event){
        if(event.rotationRate.alpha || event.rotationRate.beta || event.rotationRate.gamma)
        {
            var myImages = new Array("victoria_bg.png", "victoria_bg_2.png", "victoria_bg_3.png", "victoria_bg_4.png");
            var random = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length)];
            random = 'url(<?php echo base_url();?>resources/mobile/images/' + random + ')';
        } 
    });
```

Comment: The [devicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicemotion_event) *event is fired at a regular interval* - so it's not a traditional event like `click` but fires constantly.   You'll need to store the previous event's values and compare to see if it's changed.

Comment: @freedomn-m can you please write down a code to do so. i am newbie in jquery

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicemotion_event)

> The `devicemotion` event is fired at a regular interval

so it's not a traditional event like `click` but fires constantly. You'll need to store the previous event's values and compare to see if it's changed.

Due to how the alpha/beta/gamma are provided, you'll likely need some tolerance.   Test the exact values being returned to determine how much tolerance/sensitivity is required in your scenario.

Here's an example:

```
var prevAlpha = 0.0;
var prevBeta = 0.0;
var prevGamma = 0.0;

window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event){
    if (event.rotationRate.alpha < (prevAlpha - 0.5) 
       || event.rotationRate.alpha > (prevAlpha + 0.5)
       || event.rotationRate.beta < (prevBeta - 0.5) 
       || event.rotationRate.beta > (prevBeta + 0.5)
       || event.rotationRate.gamma < (prevGamma - 0.5) 
       || event.rotationRate.gamma > (prevGamma + 0.5))
    {
        prevAlpha = event.rotationRate.alpha;
        prevBeta = event.rotationRate.beta;
        prevGamma = event.rotationRate.gamma;

        ... code to run on a change
    } 
});
```

(obviously can use an object / namespacing / scope to reduce global variables)

Comment: i did try this code, its still changing the background even device is static and not moving. please let me know how to handle this

Comment: You may need to add some "tolerance" rather than a straight comparison, eg `event.rotationRate.alpha < (prevAlpha - 0.5) || event.rotationRate.alpha > (prevAlpha + 0.5)` you'll need to see what the values are each time to determine how much tolerance to add.

Comment: Yes this one is working, update your answer to this new line so I can upvote it and marked it accepted